# Why base64 image in SVG cannot be shown in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, adobe

I created an SVG: a grey rectangle filled with `<pattern>`. The icons in the pattern are `<image>` with base64 svg image. I then saved this svg as a .svg file with my code.

I found the .svg I got can be correctly shown in the browser.
However, when I used Adobe Illustrator to open this .svg, the icons disappeared, only the background grey rectangle can be shown correctly. I also tried another design tool, Figma, which showed the same result as Adobe Illustrator -- only background.
But I can open this .svg correctly in [an online SVG editor](https://editor.method.ac/).

Do you know why it is like this, or how to download this svg and correctly show it in Adobe Illustrator?

Thank you in advance.

My code:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn")
btn.onclick = function(){
  console.log("save svg")
  var svgData = $("#mySVG")[0].outerHTML;
  console.log(svgData);
var svgBlob = new Blob([svgData], {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var svgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = svgUrl;
downloadLink.download = "mySVG.svg";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg id = "mySVG" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect width="200" height="200" fill="lightgrey"/>
  <rect width="200" height="200" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
  <defs>
  <pattern id="pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="40" height="40">
    <image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40"  xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></image>
  </pattern>
</defs>
</svg>

<button id="btn">Save SVG</button>
```

When I open mySVG.svg in the browser, it looks like this. This is what I want.

[image: mySVG in the browser]

When I open mySVG.svg in the Adobe Illustrator, the icon images are not shown. We can only see the background.

[image: mySVG in the Adobe Illustrator]

Comment: Maybe try inkscape then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Base64 ain't a vector image format those editors can handle

- So you decode the Base64 string to SVG with: https://www.base64decode.org
- Then clean the bloated SVG with: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg
- (optional) Edit the d-path with: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor
- Manually clean the SVG, and you end up with:

```html
<svg width="600" height="180">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="carrot" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="50" height="50">
     <path fill="darkorange" d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 
                                9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 
                                2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 
                                2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightgreen"/>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#carrot)"/>
</svg>
```